# Search webservice ignores time part on Write?

Tags: search, web-services

On my blog I got a question from Kanja Saha about the time part being ignored in a sql syntax query: http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/example-of-using-the-spservices-search-web-service/
I tested this on my environment and I couldn't get it to work.
Test scenario: two queries, one without, one with Write:

```
var queryText = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>"
queryText += "<Query>"
queryText += "<Context>"
queryText += "<QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT'>"
queryText += "SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path FROM Scope() WHERE
CONTAINS ('Deventer') ORDER BY \"Rank\" DESC"
queryText += "</QueryText>"
queryText += "</Context>"
queryText += "</Query>"
queryText += "</QueryPacket>";

var queryText2 = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>"
queryText2 += "<Query>"
queryText2 += "<Context>"
queryText2 += "<QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT'>"
queryText2 += "SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path FROM Scope() WHERE
CONTAINS ('Deventer') AND Write>'2011-02-05T17:04:38Z' ORDER BY \"Rank\" DESC"
queryText2 += "</QueryText>"
queryText2 += "</Context>"
queryText2 += "</Query>"
queryText2 += "</QueryPacket>";
```

The first query returns:

```
title: Deventer - Write: 2011-02-05T17:04:38
title: Cities - Write: 2011-03-06T08:54:19
title: Deventer - Write: 2011-02-04T10:50:24
title: Deventer - Write: 2011-02-05T17:04:54
title: Deventer - Write: 2011-02-05T17:01:25
title: Deventer - Write: 2011-02-05T17:03:40
```

And the second:

```
title: Deventer - Write: 2011-02-05T17:04:38
title: Cities - Write: 2011-03-06T08:54:19
title: Deventer - Write: 2011-02-05T17:04:54
title: Deventer - Write: 2011-02-05T17:01:25
title: Deventer - Write: 2011-02-05T17:03:40
```

The date part functions as expected, the result with Write 2011-01-04 is gone in the second set of results, but the **time** part seems ignored.

Am I doing something wrong or has anybody experienced the same behaviour?

Regards, Anita

Comment: Anita asked me this question on the SPServices site in the Discussions (http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/257785) but I didn't have a good, quick answer for her, so I suggested she post it here.

Comment: I am almost positive I tried getting this working before (and failed). I'm very interested to know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/search.queryservice.query.aspx
Not an actual answer, but an answer for now: it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be that the time part is ignored, but that there is an adjustment for timezone going on, and that that leaves the unexpected results.

What timezone is this query being run in? The query specifies a UTC time, but the results don't seem to be. Also, has the server been configured to automatically adjust for daylight saving? I've found problems when it wasn't set to.

http://www.novolocus.com/2008/05/21/the-curious-incident-of-the-date-column-in-the-night-time/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the timezone and the different places to set the time settings. 
server's time setting: UTC+1, daylight saving set 
Site's regional settings: UTC+1 web application: UTC+1 There is indeed a time difference between items in the list and the items returned by the search, the difference is one hour: item in list: Last modified at 2/5/2011 6:01 PM item from search: Write: 2011-02-05T17:01:25 Due to UTC+1 Adjusting the query with this hour didn't work so a few extra hours: AND Write>'2011-02-05T23:00:00Z' But this didn't work either.

Comment: Then all I can think is that you're right, and the time element is being ignored, which is surprising. I can't see anything wrong with your logic.

Comment: It's surprising indeed, hope it will be fixed...

Comment: Unfortunately, the Web Services seem to be a backwater. I don't know that anyone at Microsoft pays any attention to the problems with them, though I am trying my damndest to figure out how to make it happen. I'd suggest that you add something in the Commmunity Content here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/search.queryservice.query.aspx just to register the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I posted it (twice by accident, so it can't be ignored :) )